# Search for a string between two known strings

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a String with this content:

```
href="http://www.website.com/" /> [...] [...]
```

I just want to get the central part of the string. How is it possible to get the part between  @"href="" and @"" />"

Note: Even if it looks like xml-code, it is inside of a NSString.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got it!

This is the code (not very nice written):

```
NSRange rr2 = [content rangeOfString:@"href=\""];
    NSRange rr3 = [content rangeOfString:@"\" />"];
    int lengt = rr3.location - rr2.location - rr2.length;
    int location = rr2.location + rr2.length;
    NSRange aa;
    aa.location = location;
    aa.length = lengt;
    theString = [theString substringWithRange:aa];
```

Comment: It 's really not very nice written, but it was usefull for me ;)

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
NSString* newNSString =[[[theString substringFromIndex:6] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/\""]objectAtIndex:0];
```

Or

```
NSString* newNSString =[[[[theString componentsSeparatedByString:@"href=\""]objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/\""]objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Worth noting that it's quite inefficient to create those temporary array of string components.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done more compactly:

```
NSRange end = [source rangeOfString:@"\" />"];
if (end.location != NSNotFound) {
    result = [source substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6, end.location - 6)];
}
```